# pySpark gets stuck and doesn't do anything

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to connect to an Hadoop cluster locally and the first thing I do is to set this variables

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=yarnconfig
```

In `yarnconfig` I have this in `yarn-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>{Hadoop_Cluster_IP}</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8050</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Here `{Hadoop_Cluster_IP}` is a place holder for the IP address of the Hadoop cluster I'm trying to connect to, which I'm not showing for security reasons.

I need to access to a bunch files on this cluster and I test out my script by running an interactive session (`./bin/pyspark`) and do the following

```
raw_logs = sc.textFile("hdfs://{Hadoop_Cluster_IP}:{Hadoop_Cluster_PORT}/logs/20*/*/*")
```

where {Hadoop_Cluster_IP} and {Hadoop_Cluster_PORT} are placeholders for the Hadoop IP address and port number.

In order to check that the connection has been properly established, I do the following

```
raw_logs.count()
```

And I get the following

```
   16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at <stdin>:1
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 2 (count at <stdin>:1) with 54 output partitions
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 3(count at <stdin>:1)
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 3 (PythonRDD[10] at count at <stdin>:1), which has no missing parents
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(7864) called with curMem=253695, maxMem=555755765
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.7 KB, free 529.8 MB)
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(4990) called with curMem=261559, maxMem=555755765
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.9 KB, free 529.8 MB)
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on localhost:60070 (size: 4.9 KB, free: 530.0 MB)
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 4 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 54 missing tasks from ResultStage 3 (PythonRDD[10] at count at <stdin>:1)
16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 3.0 with 54 tasks
16/08/10 12:20:44 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 951563, boot = 3, init = 9691, finish = 941869
16/08/10 12:20:44 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2). 2125 bytes result sent to driver
16/08/10 12:20:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, localhost, ANY, 2224 bytes)
16/08/10 12:20:44 INFO Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4)
16/08/10 12:20:44 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://_.json:134217728+134217728
16/08/10 12:20:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 955006 ms on localhost (1/54)
    16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.7 KB, free 529.8 MB)
    16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(4990) called with curMem=261559, maxMem=555755765
    16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.9 KB, free 529.8 MB)
    16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on localhost:60070 (size: 4.9 KB, free: 530.0 MB)
    16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 4 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
    16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 54 missing tasks from ResultStage 3 (PythonRDD[10] at count at <stdin>:1)
    16/08/10 12:17:26 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 3.0 with 54 tasks
```

In the folder I'm looking at there's only 24 files (total size is nearly 4 GB), but as you can see it takes minutes to just even start the process.

Do you have any idea why is pySpark so incredibly slow?